# Navigation bar won't show after pushing a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to move from a View Controller to another.
I worte this function to use when the user tap on a button to move to the new view controller:

```
    @objc private func infoButtonTap(){
    let navVC = UINavigationController()
    navVC.addChild(AboutViewController())
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(AboutViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

The problem is that the new view controller is presented on the screen but I don't have a navigation bar and a back button to move back.
I do not use Storyboard as I want to learn coding the UI.
I tried few things I found here on Stackoverflow but none worked for me.
How can I set the new view controller to have a navigation bar with back button?

Answer (score 3):

UINavigationController has a variable **isNavigationBarHidden**

```
@objc private func infoButtonTap(){
    let navVC = UINavigationController()
    navVC.addChild(AboutViewController())
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(AboutViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the view Controller. Try this

```
let aboutVC = AboutVC()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not show the new view controller.

Comment: have you embed your current view controller in navigation controller?

Comment: I think, I'm really new to this and couldn't find something, but I'm sure I don't know exactly what to search for. Anyhow, I edited the question with what I have now. I wrote this function in the main ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write any code.

Select the Root Navigation Controller the will control the app. In the Inspector Bar, select Simulated Metrics ( The Third Selection from the Right in the Inspector) and Check the Box " Is Initial View Controller". Then connect the next View controller which will be in essence the Landing page for the app. Once you connect other View Controllers to that View controller via a button for instance ( Select the button, then press Control Key + Drag to View Controller, select Show) , you will see the navigation Bar with "Back" displayed. Once that's done, you can add other view controllers and connect them from the landing page view controller and the Navigation Bars will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For navigation to be visible and of use in an app , first you need to set up a Navigation controller with a Root view controller i.e your first controller and from there you can use push method on your navigation controller object to push a controller on to the stack.

For eg

```
let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: YourFirstViewControllerObject())
navVC.pushViewController(NewViewControllerObj(), animated: true)
```

Comment: Where should I add this lines? I tried using it now but It won't work, it won't even show the new VC.